# UICollectionView empty items are coming while deleting the cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, uicollectionviewcell

I am using collection view with custom cells ,cells having long press guestures, When I delete a particular item by drag and drop , remaining items are not properly arranging , collection view has empty items.

Below code i am using after deletion

```
[array removeObjectAtIndex:currentIndexpath.item];

[CollectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
    [CollectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:@[currentIndexpath]];
}
                         completion:^(BOOL finshed){
     [CollectionView reloadData];
 }];
```

Comment: If you're using performBatchUpdates, you don't need to call reloadData.  I might take a look at the other delegate methods.

Comment: As a style note, it's customary in Objective-C to start data types with capital letters and variables with lower-case letters.  It makes it easier to determine which is which, especially when view code fragments like this.

Answer (score 0):

You must delete that content from your collection array and need to reload the collection view.